# connect ECONNREFUSED when starting postgres server using sequelize

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to seed data from sequelize before executing docker-compose up but im getting this error upon seeding.

> ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432

this is the command im using

```
docker-compose run --rm app npm run seed
```

Upon doing docker-compose up sequelize syncs the models, but i need a way to connect to the server before before models sync so that i can do commands like seeding data, or running migrations. What should i do ?

I'll share relevant code.

**How sequelize is connecting to db**

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
} else {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    "",
    {
      host: process.env.PSQL_HOST,
      dialect: "postgres",
      pool: {
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        idle: 200000,
        // @note https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8133#issuecomment-359993057
        acquire: 1000000,
      },
    }
  );
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./server
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      PSQL_HOST: database
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-elitypescript}
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]
  client:
    build: ./client
    image: react_client
    links:
      - app
    working_dir: /home/node/app/client
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/node/app
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    command: npm run start
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env

  database:
    image: postgres:9.6.8-alpine
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 3030:5432

volumes:
  database:
```

**.entrypoint.sh**

```
# entrypoint.sh
npm run seed # my attempt to run seed first before server kicks in. but doesn't work
npm run server
```

**app.ts**

```
models.sequelize.sync().then(() => {
  httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(
      "App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode",
      app.get("port"),
      app.get("env")
    );
    console.log("  Press CTRL-C to stop\n");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you log the values of these variables inside the `process.env.DATABASE_URL`, `process.env.POSTGRES_DB`, `process.env.POSTGRES_USER`. If I understand correctly, your `sequelize` is not running in the same container as the DB. Then why is it trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: sorry for the delay. i will look into this further. but from your perspective does the setup look right ?

Comment: I don't see any problem. If you want to initialize the DB with the ORM it's OK. Most people are doing this using startup-scripts in the SQL container. Just be careful and perform some tests to see what will happen when the app container will be redeployed, to be sure you don't end up with your DB being wiped.

Comment: I see Neo, where should i console.log at ?

Comment: Sorry, new edit: above the `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {` line, log the `process.env.DATABASE_URL` variable

Comment: this is what im getting `elitypescript postgres database`

Comment: It does connect to postgres server but not automatically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219466/discussion-between-neo-anderson-and-barnowl).

Answer (score 0):

@Neo Anderson, thanks for pointing the config.json issue, i was able to resolve this issue.

So the issue is a few things. Sequelize looks for 2 files when starting up a server.

One of them is `config.json`, as per

**.sequelizerc**

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.json'),
  'models-path': path.resolve('models'),
  'seeders-path': path.resolve('dist', 'seeders'),
  'migrations-source-path' : path.resolve('migrations'),
  'migrations-compiled-path': path.resolve('dist', 'migrations')

}
```

and the query in the `models/index.js`

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
} else {
  console.log(
    process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    process.env.PSQL_HOST
  );
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(
    process.env.POSTGRES_DB,
    process.env.POSTGRES_USER,
    "",
    {
      host: process.env.PSQL_HOST,
      dialect: "postgres",
      pool: {
        max: 100,
        min: 0,
        idle: 200000,
        // @note https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/8133#issuecomment-359993057
        acquire: 1000000,
      },
    }
  );
}
```

What you must do is make sure your docker-compose.yml environment variables are passed in these two files.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./server
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      # these variables must be passed in config.json, and models/index.js 
      PSQL_HOST: database
      PSQL_PORT: 5430
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:-password}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER:-postgres}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB:-elitypescript}
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]
    ....
```

**config.json**

i know i whould be using process.env, but for now i just hardcoded my docker variables here. As i would need to make config.json into a js file.

```
{
  "development": {
    "username": "postgres",
    "password": "",
    "database": "elitypescript",
    "host": "database",
    "dialect": "postgres",
    "port": "5432"
  },

}
```

So now, docker is executing the seed, and running the server from entrypoint.sh. Everything is working as expected now.

Hope this helps anyone